# CSS style sheet doesn't link to my HTML

Tags: html, css, notepad++

for some reason my CSS style sheet isn't opening with my HTML file.

I've attached images of my HTML code and CSS code.

My CSS style sheet is saved as .css. Spelling is also correct.

I've looked through similar questions on this forum. I've tried all the solutions to no avail.

I'd be grateful for any help. Many thanks

[my HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGGsm.png)

[My CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plIC3.png)

Comment: What folder is your CSS file in, and what folder is your HTML file in?

Comment: Please **do not** link to your code. **Add** your code to the post. Also, please share the structure of your site's files and folders.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please make sure when posting code snippets to use the built in code brackets instead of posting links to screenshots.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] instead of links to pictures of your code.

Comment: Also, why is your body tag wrapped in a div tag?

Comment: Make use of the developer tools in your browser. Check the Network tab to make sure the stylesheet is loading. If you use Firefox then you can configure the Console to display CSS errors and warnings.

Comment: Why is this tagged `Notepad++` when, not only is not a question about how to use a programming feature of Notepad++, your screenshots show you using Notepad and not Notepad++!

Comment: @Quentin I'm sorry - literally just started learning to code. I guess I have a lot to learn

Comment: @HS1 Press F12 in the browser and inspect the DOM. Is your CSS file loaded?

Comment: @a.sharma it just worked!!! I'm not sure what changed. But the colour isn't working ? I tried changing it to HEX colour too

Comment: change font-color to just color and DarkGreen to darkgreen

Comment: @A.Sharma thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you having this files in the same folder? Becouse if not, you should link your CSS with path to a file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="folderName/codeacademy.css">
```

//This version will work only if you have html **file** and folder with CSS file in the same place

BTW: Why your div is outside of body O.o? 
And you don't need to specify type of stylesheet link anymore ;)

**EDIT**